# How to select another div which is inside another div?

Tags: jquery

I have a page which has many blocks of questions, like this:

```
<div class='questionBlock'>
    <div class='questionBlockTitle '><span class='sectionQuestionBlockNumber'>4. </span><span class='sectionQuestionBlockTitle'>What can they do less of?</span>

        <div class='msgErrorRequired'></div>
        <div class='expandArrow downArrow'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='questionBlockExpand formQuestionPadding'>
        <div class='sectionQuestionBlockHelpText'></div>
        <input type='hidden' value='' name='13' mandatory='True' id='13' error=''>
        <div style='width:700px;height:100px;' class='sectionItemBlock '> <span class='questionControl'>
                <textarea  id='qt_13' name='qt_13' style='width:695px;height:100px;' maxlength='100' question='13' disabled='disabled' ></textarea>
            </span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then have some JQuery which checks all of the textareas on the page, and if it finds one that hasn't been filled in, then modifies the error message div to show an error.

I have been unable to reference this error message div.

So far I have got this:

```
$("#" + value).parents(".questionBlockExpand").parents(".questionBlock").siblings(".msgErrorRequired").html(msgErrorRequired);
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Am I referencing it correctly?

Comment: But the textarea is in a different div from the .msgErrorRequired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue seems like its because .msgErrorRequired is not a sibling of . questionBlock. Try:

```
$("#" + value).parents(".questionBlockExpand").parents(".questionBlock").find(".msgErrorRequired").html(msgErrorRequired);
```

You could simplify this too:

```
$("#" + value).closest('.questionBlock').find(".msgErrorRequired").html(msgErrorRequired);
```

Comment: I missed it out in the question, but I did actually try adding a second sibling for the questionBlockTitle.

Comment: Updated my answer with a shorter solution for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this:

***Edit: to reflect optimizations from comments***

```
$("#" + value).parents(".questionBlock")
              .find(".msgErrorRequired").html(msgErrorRequired);
```

Comment: You don't need the first `.parents` and you're better off using `.find` rather than `.children` incase you change your html structure.  (children only looks one level, find looks all levels)

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```js
$('.noEmpty').each(function() {
  var msgErrorRequired = 'You can\'t leave this field empty!';
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.val().trim() == '') {
    $this.closest(".questionBlock").find(".msgErrorRequired").html(msgErrorRequired);
  }

});
```

```css
.msgErrorRequired {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='questionBlock'>
  <div class='questionBlockTitle '><span class='sectionQuestionBlockNumber'>4. </span><span class='sectionQuestionBlockTitle'>What can they do less of?</span>

    <div class='msgErrorRequired'></div>
    <div class='expandArrow downArrow'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='questionBlockExpand formQuestionPadding'>
    <div class='sectionQuestionBlockHelpText'></div>
    <input type='hidden' value='' name='13' mandatory='True' id='13' error=''>
    <div style='width:700px;height:100px;' class='sectionItemBlock '> <span class='questionControl'>
                <textarea  id='qt_13' name='qt_13' class="noEmpty" style='width:695px;height:100px;' maxlength='100' question='13' disabled='disabled' ></textarea>
            </span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion - written while others added theirs

```js
$(function() { // can be on submit
  $("textarea[name^='qt']").each(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    $(this).closest(".questionBlock")
    .find(".msgErrorRequired")
    .html(val==""?"Please fill in":"");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='questionBlock'>
  <div class='questionBlockTitle '><span class='sectionQuestionBlockNumber'>4. </span><span class='sectionQuestionBlockTitle'>What can they do less of?</span>

    <div class='msgErrorRequired'>sss</div>
    <div class='expandArrow downArrow'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='questionBlockExpand formQuestionPadding'>
    <div class='sectionQuestionBlockHelpText'></div>
    <input type='hidden' value='' name='13' mandatory='True' id='13' error=''>
    <div style='width:700px;height:100px;' class='sectionItemBlock '> <span class='questionControl'>
                <textarea  id='qt_13' name='qt_13' style='width:695px;height:100px;' maxlength='100' question='13'  >This is not empty</textarea>
            </span>

    </div>
  </div>
<div class='questionBlock'>
  <div class='questionBlockTitle '><span class='sectionQuestionBlockNumber'>5. </span><span class='sectionQuestionBlockTitle'>What can they do more of?</span>

    <div class='msgErrorRequired'>sss</div>
    <div class='expandArrow downArrow'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='questionBlockExpand formQuestionPadding'>
    <div class='sectionQuestionBlockHelpText'></div>
    <input type='hidden' value='' name='14' mandatory='True' id='14' error=''>
    <div style='width:700px;height:100px;' class='sectionItemBlock '> <span class='questionControl'>
                <textarea  id='qt_14' name='qt_14' style='width:695px;height:100px;' maxlength='100' question='14'  ></textarea>
            </span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
$("#" + value + ' .questionBlockExpand .msgErrorRequired').html(msgErrorRequired);
```

Comment: Err.. no.   It's **highly** unlikely that the expandblock / errormessage will be *children* of a *textarea*.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work. I don't think #value is at the top here.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I've copied the code provided by user2924019, that uses some value as id, and then find the other divs by class.

Comment: Yes but in his code above value refers to the textarea. Your code above would treat textarea as the top level element and would find those classes below it which is not the case. questionBlockExpand is a parent of #value.

Comment: @freedomn-m erromessage div cannot be child of textarea, it's not allowed a div to be nested a textarea tag, it can be a sibling

Comment: @RicardoPontual I suspect you'll find that that was my exact point.   `$("#"+value)` refers to a *textarea*.  So *your* answer's code is trying to find divs nested in a text area.